# Is dagger2 necessary in firebase project?

Tags: android, firebase, jsr330

I know firebase + android architecture 1.0 is a good combination.

but how about firebase + android architecture 1.0 + dagger2?

I am creating a social app and I have been studying on the Internet alone and I am confused.

I did a lot of research. but I did not get a clear answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no requirement to use Dagger in a project that uses Firebase. Whether you do is a matter of personal preference.